# How to trigger framer motion animation onClick

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am applying a slide in animation using framer motion which slides in the User Card below on page render, but I want to trigger the animation on click of a button

Code below

```
const wrapperVariants = {
  hidden: { 
    opacity: 0, 
    x: '100vw' 
  },
  visible: { 
    opacity: 1, 
    x: 0,
    transition: { type: 'spring', delay: 0.1 }
  },
  exit: {
    x: "-100vh",
    transition: { ease: 'easeInOut' }
  }
};

<motion.div
  variants={wrapperVariants}
  initial="hidden"
  animate="visible"
  exit="exit"
>
  <UserCard />
</motion.div>

<button onClick={() => {
  // I want to Trigger the Animation on button click, not just on render
}}></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [animation control hook in framer motion](https://www.framer.com/docs/use-animation-controls/) and for your case it would be something like this:

```
const wrapperVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: '100vw',
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0,
    transition: { type: 'spring', delay: 0.1 },
  },
  exit: {
    x: '-100vh',
    transition: { ease: 'easeInOut' },
  },
};

const controls = useAnimationControls();

<motion.div
  variants={wrapperVariants}
  initial="hidden"
  animate={controls}
  exit="exit"
>
  <UserCard />
</motion.div>

<button onClick={() => controls.start('visible')}></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

<motion.div
  variants={wrapperVariants}
  initial="hidden"
  animate= {clicked ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
  exit="exit"
>

<button onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}></button>
```

Comment: @Otis I slightly edited the code I provided to use useState. The example I gave works, you can see a similar example in the official doc https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/#variants